# is cas-discovery-server-overlay a must

Tags: cas, netflix-eureka

cas-discovery-server-overlay is a WAR Overlay for the Service Discovery Server.

Can spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server instead of cas-discovery-server-overlay as registration center?

cas-discovery-server-overlay's doc:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Service-Discovery-Guide-Eureka.html

i haved readed the cas-discovery-server-overlay's doc:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Service-Discovery-Guide-Eureka.html .

and there are two plans i need to choose.

one is using cas-overlay to work as eureka client + spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server to work as eureka server.

the other one is using cas-overlay to work as eureka client + cas-discovery-server-overlay to work as eureka server.

so,Are both plans feasible? How do I choose?

Answer (score 0):

> Can spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server instead of cas-discovery-server-overlay as registration center?

Yes.

> so,Are both plans feasible?

Yes. Both are the same plan.